# Angular: Trying CORS $.get on non-JSONP urls

Tags: angularjs, jsonp, cors

Getting the target url of a `301` redirect from a shortened URL within
AngularJS.

1) The plain old $http.get on a regular website fails
with `"Access-Control-Origin"` not allowed.

2) Then, issuing a JSONP-Call will work, but of course the callback
fails when trying to parse the response.

Searched up and down, deleted `"X-Requested-With"` header with no luck.
Any clues?

Comment: Try adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to your response. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: I have no control over the response, as these are other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is simply impossible.
Workaround: Resolve URLs in backend, which is of course totally inefficient.